# Clustered cache in Grails 2.4.x

Tags: grails, distributed-caching, session-replication

**I need suggestions on cache clustering for Grails at the most recent version I can get.**

I've been trying to set up Terracotta with Grails 2.4.4 but I can't manage to find a compatible version of its plugin (by the way, the Terracotta plugin page says it was last updated 6 years ago). Also I can't find any recent posts on cache clustering for grails.
I'm planning on using it also for session replication. I'm using Apache Shiro for authentication/authorization. But that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache has an embedded distributed solution based on RMI. I'm gonna give it a try but I'm not sure it'll work for web sessions in grails since the [documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/recipes/grails#clustering-web-sessions) says to use Terracotta.